# Reduction of matrix $A$ to $B$ to find eigenvalues by Power method

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

How to reduce matrix $A$ to $B$ such that it has all eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$ but the **dominant eigenvalue** *(eigenvalue with largest magnitude)* is replace by $0$ ?

I am using Power method to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. The article says that by using above method, one can find not only the dominant eigenvalue but also the other eigenvalues.

Comment: See the answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1114777/approximate-the-second-largest-eigenvalue-and-corresponding-eigenvector-given/1114855#1114855

Comment: @KittyL: Oops !! My question is a duplicate. Thanks for providing information.