# Find more than one eigenvalue and eigenvector using the Power Iteration method on a generalized eigenproblem

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

Consider the generalized eigenproblem:

$$
[K]\{u\} = \omega^2 [M]\{u\} 
$$

One can transform the generalized eigenproblem into the standard eigenproblem:

$$
[D] = [K]^{-1}[M]
$$

$$
[D]\{u\} =\lambda\{u\} \qquad \text{where} \qquad \lambda=\frac{1}{\omega^2}
$$

And then, to compute the largest $\lambda$ (or the lowest $\omega^2$), $\lambda_1$, one can use the Power Iteration method, iterating the following expression (also obtaining the first eigenvector, $\{u\}$):

$$
\{u\}_{k+1} = [D]\{u\}_k \qquad \text{and} \qquad \frac{||\{u\}_{k+1}||}{||\{u\}_k||} \rightarrow \lambda_1 \qquad \text{as} \qquad k \rightarrow \infty
$$

[As answered here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1114777/approximate-the-second-largest-eigenvalue-and-corresponding-eigenvector-given/1114855), to find the next largest $\lambda$, $\lambda_2$, one can replace $[D]$ by:

$$
[B] = [D] - \lambda_1 \{u\}\{u\}^T
$$

And reiterate:

$$
\{v\}_{k+1} = [B]\{v\}_k \qquad \text{and} \qquad \frac{||\{v\}_{k+1}||}{||\{v\}_k||} \rightarrow \lambda_2 \qquad \text{as} \qquad k \rightarrow \infty
$$

And so on for the next largest eigenvalue and associated eigenvector.

**However**

The presented method consists in first calculating $[D]$. When dealing with large sparse systems, where $[M]$ and $[K]$ are stored in a CSR format, calculating $[D]$ is just not an option.

As shown in this [PDF](http://stanford.edu/group/frg/course_work/AA242B/CA-AA242B-Ch6.pdf), one can divide the Power Iteration method in two steps:

$$
\{x\}_k = [M]\{u\}_k
$$

$$
[K]\{u\}_{k+1} = \{x\}_k
$$

This works very well as one only needs to factor $[K]$ once, and only needs to solve a linear system instead of calculating $[D]$.

**My question is**

With the second, more efficient method, how does one calculate the second and following eigevalues and eigenvectors?

Answer (score 1):

You apply the subspace iteration method preferably with Ritz acceleration. This is a generalization of the power method which works on a tall matrix rather than a single vector. The subspace iteration method is also known as known as simultaneous iteration. Peter Arbenz has a good chapter on the subject with more details than most. See this [page](http://people.inf.ethz.ch/arbenz/ewp/Lnotes/chapter8.pdf)

---

Do not apply repeated deflation as this is not only highly inefficient (memory bound), but also highly inaccurate as previous rounding errors are magnified for each new vector.